# Pug: Conditional parent div without copying children

Tags: pug

We have something like this:

```
 .child
   a.child-2
     img(src)
```

if i want to add wrapper for this elements i do it like:

```
if something === true
  .parent
     .child
       a.child-2
         img(src)
else
     .child
       a.child-2
         img(src)
```

If there are a lot of children we have a problem of doubling and bad readability
How do i write a condition for wrapper element alone wihout need to make else statement and copy every child in it?

Comment: So the content is sometimes wrapped in a wrapper if the conditional is true?

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use-case for a [Pug mixin with a mixin block](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-blocks):

```
mixin conditionalWrapper(arg)
  if arg
    .parent
       block
  else
    block
```

The `block` declaration renders any children of the mixin. It can be used like this. If the argument is `true`, the contents will be rendered within the `.parent` wrapper. If it's false, they'll be rendered without the wrapper.

```
- let something = true

+conditionalWrapper(something)
  .child
    a.child-2
     img(src)
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. But can you help me with more complex case. What if i already have a mixin and i want to make this conditional wrapper inside it. For example [link](https://codepen.io/SOlid_Michael/pen/QWNjmdN) . And i want to make this wrapper over .step__item . I read you can't pass mixin as an argument for another mixin or am i wrong?

Comment: My mixin takes an array of objects as an argument. I want to make conditional wrapper if specific property is defined in object

Comment: You can call mixins from within other mixins

Comment: Please post that specific example as a new question if you get stuck on how to apply it